# How can I import in Python simple coding error

Tags: python

I have started any coding for example: `from PIL import Image`, I encountered such an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    from PIL import Image
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'
```

I will be pleased that guide me.

Comment: have you made sure that is module `PIL` is installed in your machine?

Comment: Have you installed it with `pip install Pillow`?

Comment: is the import on your system path?

Comment: Make sure you are running the version of python under which the module is installed.

Answer (score 1):

In shell, run:

```
pip install Pillow
```

PIL is deprecated - Pillow is its replacement

Answer (score 0):

This means that the package is not installed. To install it, you will need `pip`, a package installer for python.

Here is the Pillow package official website, which you can use to understand how to install the package: https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html. All the commands on the site are typed into Terminal on MacOS and Linux and the cmd on Windows.